# How to copy rows of specific columns based on a criteria (and then continuously update)?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, spreadsheet, google-spreadsheets

I have 2 sheets, let's call them sheet 1 and sheet 2.

In sheet 1, I have some data where essentially at its core its a Scoring tally, something like this:

| Name | Age | Gender | Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jack | 12 | Male | 155 |
| Mary | 67 | Female | 0 |
| Jill | 16 | Female | 61 |
| Sarah | 44 | Female | 219 |
| Peter | 5 | Male | 0 |
| Nathan | 32 | Male | 0 |
| Greg | 25 | Male | 44 |

I want to then create a new table in sheet 2, where I collect all the rows that have a score greater than 0, and only the Name and Score columns, like this:

| Name | Score |
| --- | --- |
| Jack | 155 |
| Jill | 61 |
| Sarah | 219 |
| Greg | 44 |

I want this to be continually updated, so for example, if Mary gains a few points, I would want the table to look like:

| Name | Score |
| --- | --- |
| Jack | 155 |
| Mary | 21 |
| Jill | 61 |
| Sarah | 219 |
| Greg | 44 |

And if any newcomers come, and they have more than 0 points, I would also like that to be added. For example if Luke joined:

| Name | Score |
| --- | --- |
| Jack | 155 |
| Mary | 21 |
| Jill | 61 |
| Sarah | 219 |
| Greg | 44 |
| Luke | 98 |

I am not really sure where to begin with this, I am working on google sheets, and have tried to do INDEX-MATCH, but my issues are that match doesn't seem to do greater than nicely, I can't seem to choose the pairs of column I want displayed, and I am also not sure how to get it to continuously update. I would prefer a solution with no use of VBAs, and if possible to just keep it to formulas in the cells.

Comment: If you use Excel 365, then you can use [FILTER](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759) function, it does exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your google spreadsheets sheet two

enter the following formula where you want your table

```
=SORT(FILTER(FILTER(Sheet1!A:D,Sheet1!D:D>0),{1,0,0,1}),2,FALSE)
```

The first filter '`FILTER(Sheet1!A:D,Sheet1!D:D>0)`' chooses the cell range and scores column where score is greater than 0.

Wrap this filter in another filter to only return data '`{1,0,0,1}`' from the first (Name) and forth (Score) columns.

Wrap this to sort the second column (`2`) and sort descending (`False`).

If doing this in Excel 365 then substitue False for `-1`

Comment: Thanks a lot Antony, this was exactly what I was looking for :)